# .NET Core, SignalR Hub's constructor IHubCallerClients is NULL

Tags: signalr, .net-core-2.2

I'm trying to implement .NET Core 2.2/SignalR 1.1.0.

In startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   services.AddSignalR();

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   app.UseSignalR(routes =>
   {
     routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
   });
```

It works smoothly when I apply a one-to-one example.

But I need an architectural change.

My example:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    ResponseHandler ResponseHandler { get; set; }

    public ChatHub()
    {
        IHubCallerClients hubCallerClients = this.Clients;
        ResponseHandler = new ResponseHandler(hubCallerClients);
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        IHubCallerClients hubCallerClients = this.Clients;
        await ResponseHandler.R();
    }
}
```

If I tried to get **this.Clients** in the constructor it is coming with null data. But if I try to take it in the method, it comes full as expected.

I should get IHubCallerClients in the contructor so that I can forward it to another Response context.

Thanks advance!

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information about the root problem you're trying to solve? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem It looks like you're trying to solve "forwarding requests", but you're asking about "how to get this.Clients in the constructor?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I solved the problem by

```
public class RequestHandler : Hub
{
    ResponseHandler ResponseHandler { get; set; }

    public RequestHandler(IHubContext<RequestHandler> hubContext)
    {
        ResponseHandler = new ResponseHandler(hubContext);
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await ResponseHandler.R();
    }
}
```

Due to the nature of .net core, context comes to constructor as dependency.
"**services.AddSignalR();**" we're sure to add it to Scope.
"**IHubContext hubContext**" In this way, we can collect the contructured object.